# How to rename file from the specific pattern within the file

Tags: unix, rename

I would like to change the file name according to the specific pattern within the file. Let's say I have the unique pattern that starts with "XmacTmas". I would like to use this pattern to rename the file with the additional character like "_dbp1".

Now my file name is "xxo1" and I want "XmacTmas_dbp1".

How can I do this in for thousands of files with some script.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
find . -name 'XmacTmas*' -exec echo mv {} {}_dbp1 \;
```

`find` the files of interest and execute command after replacing `{}` with the found filename.
Escape the `;`.  Without the `\`, find would take it as part of the command to execute.

If only files in the actual directory are needed, add `-maxdepth 0` before `-name` (or any other of find's numerous options)

If the result is as needed, remove the `echo`